# Ionic plugin need to remove platform and read platform before it works

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have package.json like this,

```
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "com.ionic.keyboard",
    "org.apache.cordova.camera",
    "org.apache.cordova.console",
    "org.apache.cordova.device",
    "org.apache.cordova.dialogs",
    "org.apache.cordova.file",
    "org.apache.cordova.file-transfer",
    "org.apache.cordova.geolocation",
    "org.apache.cordova.network-information",
    "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
  ]
```

The root project directory does not have plugins and platforms directory,
when I pull from repository. so I run "ionic platform add android", which will create the platforms directory and install the plugin.

But it does not work, until I run "ionic platform rm android" then "ionic platform add android" again, suddenly it works fine.

What cause this? and how to solve this, so next developer can pull the repo and directly make it work just by running "ionic platform add android" once?

I'm using latest cordova

Comment: Did you have the chance to try my solutions?

Comment: @LeftyX sorry I haven't had a chance to test your solution. Right now I solve it by, initializing plugin on init.js before platform add. I'll try your solution next. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add all your plugins using the option `--save`:

```
cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard --save
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera --save
```

etc etc.

Or you can do it after all your plugins have been added:

```
cordova plugin save
```

You can do the same thing for your platform:

```
cordova platform add android --save
```

or later:

```
cordova platform save
```

these commands will add some new sections to your **config.xml** file:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" spec="^0.3.0" />
...
```

and

```
<engine name="android" spec="^4.0.0" />
```

now you can delete **platforms** and **plugins** folder and run:

```
cordova prepare
```

and it should create the platform and download all the plugins for you.

You can find some more info [here](http://devgirl.org/2015/04/24/apache-cordova-newsflash/).

Answer (score 6):

Following steps helped me

```
ionic platform rm android
ionic platform add android
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
ionic build android
```

Then you can deploy your apk

Answer (score 1):

Following steps
Step 1:C:\Users\vipin>cd C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin

//change directory ,where your app is Located

Step 2: ionic platform add android // or ios
ex:C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin>ionic platform add android

Step 3: ionic build android
ex :C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin> ionic build android

Step 4: if you want to remove your platform . follow this step 
C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin>ionic platform rm android

Note : again you want to add platform . please go through step 1 to step 3